# How to programmatically invoke interactive function?

Tags: interactive, sql-mode

I have written an interactive  function to connect to multiple mysql databases

```
(defun mysql-connect (name)
  "Connect to a predefined MySQL connection."
  (interactive
   (list
    (completing-read "Connect to: " sql-connection-alist
             nil t nil 'pyvenv-workon-history nil nil)))
  (when (not (or (equal name "")
             (equal name nil)))
    (mysql-connect-preset name)))
```

If I run `M-x mysql-connect`, it  will prompt user to select available options. But I  want to invoke it via script.

If I  run `(mysql-connect 'some-choice)`  it will  work, but I dont want  that. I just want to invoke `mysql-connect`  and let  user  to select choice.

How  can I just  invoke  that function?

Comment: Doesn't simply evaluating `(mysql-connect)` offer you the choices in the same manner as an interactive call?

Comment: No, it will throw error as it requires one argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `call-interactively` here.

Usage example:

```el
(call-interactively #'foo)
```

You can learn more about it by doing `C-h i g (elisp) Interactive Call` and `C-h f call-interactively`.